# device_info_plus not showing device data | Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to show device information(using device_info_plus package) on a modal bottom sheet, but the modal bottom sheet doesn't give any detail regarding the device.

I'm guessing in modal bottom sheet the initState() of the StatefulWidget doesn't run at all.

What's the way around?

This is my device_details.dart file

```
class DeviceDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeviceDetailsState createState() => _DeviceDetailsState();
}

class _DeviceDetailsState extends State<DeviceDetails> {
  static final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  Map<String, dynamic> _deviceData = <String, dynamic>{};

  final TextStyle _devicePropertyName = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black87,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 14.sp,
  );
  final TextStyle _devicePropertyValue = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 14.sp,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    var deviceData = <String, dynamic>{};

    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        deviceData = _readAndroidBuildData(await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo);
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      deviceData = <String, dynamic>{
        'Error:': 'Failed to get platform version.'
      };
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _deviceData = deviceData;
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _readAndroidBuildData(AndroidDeviceInfo build) {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'version.securityPatch': build.version.securityPatch,
      'version.sdkInt': build.version.sdkInt,
      'version.release': build.version.release,
      'version.previewSdkInt': build.version.previewSdkInt,
      'version.incremental': build.version.incremental,
      'version.codename': build.version.codename,
      'version.baseOS': build.version.baseOS,
      'board': build.board,
      'bootloader': build.bootloader,
      'brand': build.brand,
      'device': build.device,
      'display': build.display,
      'fingerprint': build.fingerprint,
      'hardware': build.hardware,
      'host': build.host,
      'id': build.id,
      'manufacturer': build.manufacturer,
      'model': build.model,
      'product': build.product,
      'supported32BitAbis': build.supported32BitAbis,
      'supported64BitAbis': build.supported64BitAbis,
      'supportedAbis': build.supportedAbis,
      'tags': build.tags,
      'type': build.type,
      'isPhysicalDevice': build.isPhysicalDevice,
      'androidId': build.androidId,
      'systemFeatures': build.systemFeatures,
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Brand :',
                    style: _devicePropertyName,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'product :',
                    style: _devicePropertyName,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Model :',
                    style: _devicePropertyName,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Manufacturer :',
                    style: _devicePropertyName,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Id :',
                    style: _devicePropertyName,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Android Id :',
                    style: _devicePropertyName,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '${_deviceData['brand']}',
                    style: _devicePropertyValue,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${_deviceData['product']}',
                    style: _devicePropertyValue,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${_deviceData['model']}',
                    style: _devicePropertyValue,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${_deviceData['manufacturer']}',
                    style: _devicePropertyValue,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${_deviceData['id']}',
                    style: _devicePropertyValue,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${_deviceData['androidId']}',
                    style: _devicePropertyValue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show the above details in modal bottom sheet. Also I don't want to merge this file with the file(screen), where I want show it. TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

I think one way is that ->

Let's say you have a gesture detector and in its on tap method you do ->

1. Show a bottom modal sheet with a loader first

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return SafeArea(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          CircularProgressIndicator()
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
```

2. Then you do your async calls
3. And store it in some variables.

Then

```
  Navigator.pop(context);
```

4. This will pop the first modal sheet
5. Then open another modal sheet with all the data.